# Bitcoin API with bech32 support

Tags: segregated-witness, bech32-address, blockchain-explorer, insight-api

Since a while, I have been using the insight-api to view bitcoin transactions. However, recently I have found out that bech32 addresses are not supported.

Now I try to fix this issue and I am open for any suggestions.

It there some other suitable api that also supports bech32-addresses? Or, also appreciated, is there some workaround available for the insight-api

Answer (score 1):

It looks like [bitcore](https://github.com/bitpay/bitcore) replaced the insight-api

Comment: Does this mean there is a new api for bitcoin? Isn't bitcore another crypto-currency?

Comment: No, these are all just different implementations of the bitcoin core protocol. Just like how you can use Google Chrome or Firefox to access the web, you can use insight-api or bitcore to access bitcoin data.

Comment: Thanks for the comment! This makes it clear to me.

Answer (score 1):

There are bunch of [blockexplorer APIs](https://en.bitcoin.it/wiki/Bech32_adoption) that support Bech32 addresess:

- [Blockonomics](https://www.blockonomics.co/views/api.html)
- [ChainFlyer](https://chainflyer.bitflyer.jp/API/docs)
- [BTC.com](https://btc.com/api-doc)